# General Formula for possible combinations of Android-lock NxN matrix

Tags: android, matrix, passwords, combinations, combinatorics

There was a similar Post here for a 3x3 Matrix: [android lock password combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979524/android-lock-password-combinations) .

I'm not able to figure out a formula to find the possible combinations in general with a NxN matrix.
My Phone for example has the possibility to chose between a 5x5 and a 6x6 Matrix
for my unlock pattern and i would like to know how much more secure the 6x6 is in comparison to 5x5.

Restrictions for the patterns are: Minimum 1 Point, maximum N*N points, no point can be hit 2 times and you can't skip points in diagonal, horizontal and vertical lines from the actual point of your pattern.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for someone to answer you, you must provide the code and efforts that you have tried.

Comment: The question is actually about a general abstract algorithm, so I wouldn't necessarily expect any code yet.